# Using sphinx for very basic structure

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

This is my file hierarchy:

InfoRescue
|
|_ src
|
|_ _ _ includes
|
|_ _ _ _ _ i1.py
|_ _ _ _ _ i2.py
|_ _ _ _ _ **init**.py
|
|_ _ _ utils
|
|_ _ _ _ _ u1.py
|_ _ _ _ _ u2.py
|_ _ _ _ _ **init**.py
|
|_ _ _ doc
|
|_ _ _ _ _ index.rst
|_ _ _ _ _ project.rst
|_ _ _ _ _ contact.rst
|_ _ _ _ _ api
|
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ api.rst
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ includes.rst
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ utils.rst

I am using Sphinx to generate the documentation. Everything related to sphinx is in `doc` directory.

**My index.rst:**

```
.. InfoRescue documentation master file, created by
   sphinx-quickstart on Sun Sep 15 13:52:12 2013.
   You can adapt this file completely to your liking, but it should at least
   contain the root `toctree` directive.

Welcome to InfoRescue's documentation!
======================================

Contents:
========

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   project
   api/api
   contact

Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

**api.rst**:

```
InfoRescue API
**********

.. toctree::
    :glob:
    :maxdepth: 1

    **
```

Now inside the utils there are to .py files. Both of these files contain no class and direct code, both only contain functions. To document a function I can use `.. autofunction:: utils.u1.functionName`. This is working correctly but I have to write like this for every function. **Is there any short way to simply include all the functions?**

Suppose both files in includes directory contain no class and function only some (direct) code. **How to generate document for it i.e. which auto-directive to use ?**

Also both the **init**.py files inside the utils and includes directory are empty. I made those two so that I can access the files inside those directory from .rst files. **Is there any other approach so that I don't have to create _*init*_.py files?**

Answer (score 0):

There is a default extension for Sphinx called [autosummary](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autosummary.html) which has the ability to scan your source code and automatically generate the Sphinx input files containing the necessary `autofunction` directives.

Answer (score 0):

For the *(direct)* code, you need to provide that documentation in the first docstring of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Presence of the "__init__.py" file marks the directory as a Python *package*.  You don't *need* to do that for Sphinx.  Instead, you can place the directory contents on the Python path by editing the "src/doc/conf.py" file, adding line(s) after the "import sys, os" line such as:

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', 'utils')))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..', '..', 'includes')))
```

Of course, if you place docstrings into both "utils/__init__.py" and  "includes/__init__.py" and try to document them both using Sphinx with these path additions, then you will have to do more work.

Answer (score 0):

autosummary generates a table

You may rather wish to use something like [automodule](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html?highlight=automodule#directive-automodule) in your .rst file:

```
.. automodule:: i1
   :members:
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving the answer above of @BarryPie, and having this problem of having to add all the `sys.path.insert` for all the subpackages, I'm using this code in my `conf.py` :

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('../../src'): # path to my source code
    if '__pycache__' not in root: #__pycache__ folder excluded
        sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(root))
```

and all the subpackages are imported as requested.